# Difference between List items

Tags: java, arraylist

i have two lists ListOne and ListTwo.
I have to find out all the elements of ListOne which does not exist in ListTwo.
Similarly 
I have to find out all the elements of ListTwo which does not exist in ListOne .

My below code is working , but i am thinking there might be some better way

```
        List<Long> listOne=...Some valid values;
        List<Long> listTwo=...Some valid values;
        List<Long> listThree=new ArrayList<Long>();
        List<Long> listFour=new ArrayList<Long>();

    for (Long id: ListOne) {
        if(!listTwo.contains(id)){
            listThree.add(id);
        }
    }

    for (Long id: ListTwo) {
        if(!listOne.contains(id)){
            listFour.add(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718621/4994582

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the difference between two ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919387/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-arraylists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do union, intersect, difference and reverse data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-do-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java)

Comment: Also note that for length of first list `m` and second `n`, this will have `m*n` time complexity. If the lists are short, no problem. However, it could prove troublesome with long lists.

Comment: You are describing an algebra of sets operation, difference. You should be using a java.util.Set implementation. If you can use Guava, com.google.common.collect.Sets is a nice class with sets utilities.

Answer (score 3):

Below should work for you

```
List<Long> listOne =...Some valid values;
List<Long> listTwo =...Some valid values;

List<Long> listThree = new ArrayList<>(listOne);
List<Long> listFour = new ArrayList<>(listTwo);
listThree.removeAll(listTwo);
listFour.removeAll(listOne);
```

From the java doc:

> **RemoveAll:** Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

Comment: Nice to mention both, but `removeAll` is what OP asked for.

Comment: `removeAll()` simplifies really the processing. Nicer but your code modification has a mistake. You perform the operation on `listTwo`, the existing list.

Comment: @davidxxx oh yeah i removed too much when I edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to Lino answer, you can also rewrite your code in a functional way  :

```
List<Long> listOneButListTwoElements = listOne.stream()
        .filter(l-> !listTwo.contains(l))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());


List<Long> listTwoButListOneElements = listTwo.stream()
        .filter(l-> !listOne.contains(l))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yea, it is nice. It is still iterating a list in every step of the cycle though.

Comment: Vlasec is right. This is O(n²). It would be a good idea to create a temporary Set from each list and use the set instead of the list in the `.contains(l)` calls.

Comment: Yep, I actually wrote an answer of my own. The part with stream barely differs though, if only you could write `filterOut(setTwo::contains)` :)

Comment: @Vlasec I agree. A straight way to request a reverse filtering is really missing.

Comment: @Vlasec and Klitos Kyriacou  Good point to mention. About complexity drawback, it is right but it may become a problem only if you have a list with many elements. The OP doesn't specify this point.

Answer (score 3):

To be really efficient, you could do something like that:

```
Set<Long> setOne = new HashSet<>(listOne);
Set<Long> setTwo = new HashSet<>(listTwo);

List<Long> listThree = listOne.stream()
        .filter(e -> !setTwo.contains(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Long> listFour = listTwo.stream()
        .filter(e -> !setOne.contains(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way you avoid the problem with `m*n` complexity for list lengths `m` and `n`.

---

**Edit:** If you prefer having no intermediary variables (as @davidxxx mentioned), you could do it like:

```
List<Long> listThree = listOne.stream()
        .filter(not(new HashSet(listTwo)::contains))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are various ways to negate a predicate. No need to cover it here, it has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488056/how-to-negate-a-method-reference-predicate).

Comment: for big Lists this is perfect, but for small lists I'm guessing this might be a bit overkill

Comment: Nice improvement +1. But I agree with Lino.  Introducing additional  intermediary variables defeats in a some way the functional programming paradigm. It should be done only if required.

Comment: I agree, it looks better if you can write it declaratively, with no extra variables. I often prefer to write code like that. Now that I think of it, what a pity there is no opposite of `filter` called `filterOut` or something, then you could just put the sets inside like `.filterOut(new HashSet<>(listOne)::contains)` :)

Comment: Wouldn't that create a new HashSet for every element in the streamed list?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Not really. It would, if it was inside the lambda. But the way I wrote it, it is a method reference and it refers to method `contains` of the new object.

Comment: @Vlasec yes, it's a method reference, equivalent to `e -> new HashSet<>(listOne).contains(e)`. But this lambda would be applied (evaluated) by the `filterOut` method. When applied, it will create a new HashSet. It is applied for every element, therefore a new HashSet is created every time.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou The lambda would be equivalent if it was an already existing object. But this is an expression that creates one. Feel free to try out, too.

Comment: @Vlasec I see what you mean. This demonstrates that method references are not just syntactic sugar for lambdas. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose, in absence of a `filterOut` method, you could define `static <R> Predicate<R> not(Predicate<R> predicate) {
    return predicate.negate();
}` and then use `.filter(not(new HashSet<>(listOne)::contains))` :)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes, such a negation method was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488056/how-to-negate-a-method-reference-predicate - How to negate a method reference predicate. I know that topic quite well :)