# Compare the ArrayList in hasmap keys

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a Hash-map of type `String`, `ArrayList<String>`. Two different `keys` are stored in the hash-map with list of values.

Now i have to compare the values of different keys and extract the common value. How can achieve this functionality ?

Following is the type of `Hashmap` that i am using:

**Example List:**

```
{Size=[43, 53, 63, 48, 58], Color=[66, 62, 65, 64, 63]}
```

> Here is code...

```
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapMatchvalues = new HashMap<>();

     for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> map3 : mapMatchvalues.entrySet()) {
     List<String> getList1 = new ArrayList<>();
     getList1 = map3.getValue();

           for (int i = 0; i < getList1.size(); i++) {
                   if (getList.contains(getList1.get(i))) {
                    //Print values
                    } else {
                   // Print if not matched....
             }
      }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Just write a method that will compare two `List`. (the `Map` part is not relevant here). And for the method, start with [Comparing Two ArrayLists to Get Unique and Duplicate Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718548/comparing-two-arraylists-to-get-unique-and-duplicate-values)

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity: if you will only save size and color inside hashmap, what's the purpose of hashmap?

Comment: No, they may be different. For now, only these two are coming size and color. But in future, they me be different.

Comment: if you sent this type of data to server how can you do it? i want to sent it same structure but it show parse error .i dont know what can i do

Answer (score 6):

You can use [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29). Use new `ArrayList` if you don't want to effect the values in the existing lists.

```
List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(mapMatchvalues.get("key1"));
common.retainAll(mapMatchvalues.get("key2"));
```

`common` will contain the matching elements from the lists.

If you have multiple entries in the map you can loop over it

```
// initialize the common list with List
List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(mapMatchvalues.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue());
for (List<String> list : mapMatchvalues.values()) {
    common.retainAll(list);
}
```

Comment: But the Hashmap may have multiple arraylists coming from server.

Comment: @MamtaKaundal Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate your `hashmap` and see if a value matches a value from `ArrayList`.

```
HashMap<String,String> hashmap=new HashMap<String,String>();
    hashmap.put("Key ABC","ABC");
    hashmap.put("Key BCD","BCD");
    hashmap.put("Key CDE","CDE");
    hashmap.put("Key DEF","DEF");

    for(Map.Entry map : hashmap.entrySet()){
        if (list.contains(map.getValue()))
            System.out.println("VALUE: " + map.getKey());
    }
```

Comment: I think its only work on that case if you have string type value in your Hashmap. Because contains will match whole the Arraylist not the item inside the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapMatchvalues = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("43");
    list.add("53");
    list.add("63");
    list.add("48");
    list.add("58");

    list1.add("66");
    list1.add("62");
    list1.add("65");
    list1.add("64");
    list1.add("63");

    list2.add("21");
    list2.add("22");
    list2.add("23");
    list2.add("25");
    list2.add("63");

    mapMatchvalues.put("Size", list);
    mapMatchvalues.put("Color", list1);
    mapMatchvalues.put("Color1", list2);


    for (Map.Entry map : mapMatchvalues.entrySet()) {
        if (list.contains(map.getValue()))
            Log.e("VALUE: ", map.getKey() + "");
    }

    ArrayList<String> commonItem = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String item : mapMatchvalues.get("Size")) {
        if (mapMatchvalues.get("Color").contains(item) && mapMatchvalues.get("Color1").contains(item)) {
            commonItem.add(item);
        } else {
            //uniqueList.add(item);
        }
    }

    Log.e("tag", commonItem + "");
```

Comment: The array lists will be dynamic. It depends on the response coming from server. Map may contain one, two or more array list. So, how to compare them? Any idea?

Comment: So you want to find out the common value among all the arraylist ?

Comment: Yes. Any idea, how to do that?

Comment: The list count may vary. So how are you comparing like
 for (String item : mapMatchvalues.get("Size")) {
        if (mapMatchvalues.get("Color").contains(item) && mapMatchvalues.get("Color1").contains(item)) {
            commonItem.add(item);
        } else {
            //uniqueList.add(item);
        }
    }

Comment: Now i have used three different list and it may be dynamic as well. But you have to know about keys for hashmap (Because it is always unique for every arraylist) through this you can used AND operator and find the common value.If you have any problem then let me know...Thanks

Comment: I only knows the hashmap count, not the list count. So how to use this: 

for (String item : mapMatchvalues.get("Size")) {
        if (mapMatchvalues.get("Color").contains(item) && mapMatchvalues.get("Color1").contains(item)) {
            commonItem.add(item);
        } else {
            //uniqueList.add(item);
        }
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167073/discussion-between-saurabh-vadhva-and-mamta-kaundal).