# Can I stream the difference between two lists where a field is set to something specific in Java?

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have the following class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String gender;
}
```

Then I have two lists of persons

**List A:**

```
index 0: name: "Mike", gender: "male"
index 1: name: "Jane", gender: "female"
index 2: name: "Ellen", gender: "female"
index 3: name: "Ben", gender: "male"
index 4: name: "Jimmy", gender: "male"
index 5: name: "Maria", gender: "female"
```

**List B:**

```
index 0: name: "Ben", gender: "male"
index 1: name: "Maria", gender: "female"
index 2: name: "Jane", gender: "female"
index 3: name: "Brian", gender: "male"
index 4: name: "Sofia", gender: "female"
index 5: name: "John", gender: "male"
index 6: name: "Jimmy", gender: "male"
```

I want to create a new list of names of all the males that is NOT in both lists.

So from the example the list would look like this:

```
index 0: name: "Mike", gender: "male"
index 1: name: "John", gender: "male"
index 2: name: "Brian", gender: "male"
```

The tricky things here is that the filtering goes both ways. I want the final list to contain both males that are in list A but not in list B, and males that are in list B but not in list A. I've not been able to find out how to do this, but I've tried to accomplish it using streams..

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718548/comparing-two-arraylists-to-get-unique-and-duplicate-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not super efecient but works

```
List<Person> r =
  Stream.concat(
    a.stream().filter(e -> e.isMale() && !b.contains(e)),
    b.stream().filter(e -> e.isMale() && !a.contains(e))
  )
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

more readable versions with storing parial results

```
List<Person> aNotB = a.stream().filter(e -> e.isMale() && !b.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Person> bNotA = b.stream().filter(e -> e.isMale() && !a.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Person> r = new ArrayList<>(aNotB);
r.addAll(bNotA);
```

Comment: Why do we need the flatMap(Function.identity())?

Comment: besause I used `Stream.of`. `Stream.consat` can be used instead, when using `Stream.of` result is `Stream<Stream<Person>>` so flatMap flattens it to `Stream<Person>`

Comment: What does `e.isMale()` mean? Is it not `e.getGender().equals("male")` ? Also this returns a list of Person, I just want a lost of names, so a list of strings. Thank you though I'm almost there.

Comment: `isMale()` is helper method    `public boolean isMale() {return gender.equals("male"); }` also You need to override `equals` that compare fields of `Person` default 'equals' will not work, if You want list of names not `Person` You can add `.map(Person::getName)` as in answer from @Sethu Mohanan

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> malesNotInBothLists = listA.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getGender().equals("male"))
    .filter(p -> !listB.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.getName().equals(p.getName())))
    .map(Person::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

malesNotInBothLists.addAll(listB.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getGender().equals("male"))
    .filter(p -> !listA.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getName().equals(p.getName())))
    .map(Person::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));`enter code here`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).